# Sending verification request every single second to the server (repeating task)

Tags: iphone, http, servlets, oc4j, oas

I've some service that's being called by a Mobile app.

The mobile app need to be up to date with the server.

So, Every `1 second` I do check the server for any additional data, if found I got the data from the server (repeating task).

Is there any problem from sending an HTTP request every single second (most of the time the response is very small, just to tell the client no data found)?

I am using `Oracle App server` for Server and `iPhone` for Client.

Thanks.

Comment: Agreed it will just eat your clients battery and if it does that apple will reject it from going into the app store. Could you not do it every time you land on a particular page.

Answer (score 2):

It will probably eat your client's battery, and create a lot of load on your server.

You can try [commet long polling approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) or the newer (and not well supported yet) [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) instead.

Comment: Really I got lost with may techniques... Can you provide me with some `concert` example?

Comment: Sure, there are plenty of examples here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code